# Conventions in matrix and vector calculus?

Tags: calculus, optimization, vectors, matrix-calculus

I'm working on the derivation of a gradient based algorithm for computing tensor decompositions. In order to do this work I have to delve into matrix and vector calculus and looking at different sources, papers and works has left me rather confused. More specifically, I seem to run into different representations for the same gradients regarding derivations to vectors/matrices. In this context I was wondering if a lot of matrix/vector calculus is merely based on convention or is there something else going on?

**For example:**

In [these notes](https://erho.weebly.com/uploads/2/7/8/4/27841631/matrixcalc.pdf) on page 13 it is mentioned that $\dfrac{dAx}{dx} = A$ and $\dfrac{dx^TAx}{dx} = x^T(A + A^T)$ while [the matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) and [these notes](http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/teaching/courses/sntn/sntn-2017/resources/Matrix_derivatives_cribsheet.pdf) indicate that $\dfrac{dx^TA}{dx} = A$ (and thus $\dfrac{dAx}{dx} = A^T$?) and $\dfrac{dx^TAx}{dx} = 2Ax$ or even $\dfrac{dx^TAx}{dx} = (A + A^T)x$ which is again different.

**Question:**
Are there any real differences/motivations between these different representations? Or are they more or less a convention?

Comment: If you take $A$ to be a $2\times 2$-matrix and consider the expressions $x\mapsto Ax$ (and all others) as functions of two variables you are calculating Jacobian matrices, resp. gradients. This should show pretty easily which expression holds under which convention/assumption.

Comment: If you're working with tensors, then you're likely using index notation which avoids these silly transposition issues altogether.